# "связать себя брачными узами" vs "связать себя узами брака"

Tags: падежи

> связать себя **брачными** узами
>
> связать себя узами **брака**

I wonder when you use one over the other and which is considered stylistically superior: "брак" as Plural Instrumental or as Singular Genitive. I assume their meanings boil down to essentially the same .

Comment: my choice would be heavily dependent on the surrounding semantic context, so it's rather up to the gut feeling than to any ratonal decision

Comment: As for me, the second variant is more artistic and the first one is more casual, mundane.

Comment: разницы никакой

Comment: IMHO the the second form "узами брака" has a bit smoother sound to it. There is no "stylistic superiority" to either of the them.

Comment: The choice is not about genitive or instrumental. It's adjective vs noun (in the genitive): брачные узы vs узы брака, marital bonds vs bonds of marriage.

Comment: They are the same, but IIRC the second one was/is used more in the media.

Comment: _> ... "брак" as Plural Instrumental ..._ - this assumption makes no sense to me. A plural instrumental from _брак_ is _браками_.

Comment: the same as "book of Andrew", "Andrew's book"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite I'd personally prefer the second one, I believe they are completely interchangeable. I cannot imagine any nuances in meaning or usage.

Another example of completely equivalent phrases:

> Ограничить себя **моральными** нормами.
>
> Ограничить себя нормами **морали**.

Answer (score 2):

**Узами брака** sounds vaguely better because almost all uses of **брачный** describe things *functionally* related to marriage, such as **брачный контракт** (pre-nup) or **брачные игры** (a term for animal courtship), whereas here, it would atypically refer to the *essence* of **узы**.

In any case, for an expression so ornate, there's a rather narrow range of contexts in which it will not sound out of place; even its ironic use comes off a little lifeless.